# Swagger python does not support getting property of property?

Tags: swagger

I am using swagger 3.0 API. I defined an object data type which has a property of another object type, something like this:

```
schemas:
    singleinput:
      type: object
      properties:
        image:
          type: object
          properties:
            url:
              type: string
              example: www.abc.com/001.jpg
```

The generation of python SDK is ok and I want to do the following

```
input = Singleinput() #this is ok
input.image.url='xxxxx' # this is error
input.image = {"url":"xxxx"} #this is ok
```

I check the source code of the SDK, Singleinput class does have a property called image and there is actually a definition of class called SingleinputImage. The problem is input.image is nonetype, so I cannot use input.image.url.

By the way, I can do as follows:

```
image = SingleinputImage('xxxx')
input = Singleinput(image)

i.e., I explicitly specify the class type.
```

So, am I doing in the right way or it is true that swagger does not support getting property of above the second level?

===================================
This is the source code of Singleinput class. You can see that there is no way to know the data type of _image when use dot notation. My guess is this is the reason.

```
Do not edit the class manually.
    """
    """
    Attributes:
      swagger_types (dict): The key is attribute name
                            and the value is attribute type.
      attribute_map (dict): The key is attribute name
                            and the value is json key in definition.
    """
    swagger_types = {
        'image': 'SingleinputImage'
    }

    attribute_map = {
        'image': 'image'
    }

    def __init__(self, image=None):  # noqa: E501
        """Singleinput - a model defined in Swagger"""  # noqa: E501
        self._image = None
        self.discriminator = None
        if image is not None:
            self.image = image

    @property
    def image(self):
        """Gets the image of this Singleinput.  # noqa: E501


        :return: The image of this Singleinput.  # noqa: E501
        :rtype: SingleinputImage
        """
        return self._image

    @image.setter
    def image(self, image):
        """Sets the image of this Singleinput.


        :param image: The image of this Singleinput.  # noqa: E501
        :type: SingleinputImage
        """

        self._image = image
```

Comment: How did you generate the SDK? Did you use [OpenAPI Generator](https://openapi-generator.tech) or some other codegen? Can you post the exact command and/or config file you used to generate the SDK?

Comment: I use swagger-codegen-cli.jar with most default option, only specify -l and sdk name.